# How can websites that block your IP address be accessed with SmartDNS and can website owners do anything to stop it?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, proxy

I use [Control D](https://controld.com) and redirect all of my traffic to look like they originate form somewhere in US, then I can access websites and apps that blocked me or my country's IP block from accessing them.
Control D or other SmartDNS services proxy DNS requests to appear from another location, but my first question is, how can websites be tricked into thinking I'm from another location even though my IP address that is sent to the website is still the same?

(my original IP address isn't changed and the website should be able to see which IP address they are giving service to.)

my second question is, can websites implement something that will even prevent users that use SmartDNS services from accessing them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

DNS is the addressbook of the Internet: you ask for a domain and DNS tells you the IP address where you should look.

Control D's trick is that they don't give you the real IP address, but the IP of their proxy server. Your browser doesn't realize that's the case and proceeds as usual: it tries to set up an HTTPS connection with that proxy server. A part of this process is telling the server which domain the browser is expecting to see. Control D's server uses this to know where you're trying to connect and set up an identical connection with the real server. Then they forward everything to you.

It's essentially a consensual man-in-the-middle.

The server of the website doesn't see your IP, because your IP is talking to the proxy, and proxy is talking to the target website.

Possible countermeasures for website admins are limited to blocking proxy server IPs. But if the proxy is hosted in a large cloud (eg. AWS, Azure, GCP) its provider will be able to change IPs quickly and blocking entire cloud would do too much collateral damage.

Note that the connection to the proxy still uses plaintext SNI, so your ISP can see which website you're trying to visit.

Comment: Counter point to blocking an entire could would do too much collateral damage, is that the cloud may view a user causing the entire cloud community to get blocked is a malicious user and close down the proxy. It depends on the size and popularity of the site doing the blocking.

Comment: It's possible to check if IP is from residential user or from datacenter. Not too reliable but possible. There are services who provide this as service. So site could just refuse to talk if they think request is not from 'real' user.

Answer (score 6):

Control-D is very similar to VPN in the sense that it redirects all your
requests to servers in 60 countries, so your traffic seems to come from
your chosen server with a different (local) IP address.
So yes, your IP address **is** changed.

Unlike a VPN, it uses proxies, so your communications with these servers
are not encrypted and can be read by any man-in-the-middle node.

Reference : [FAQ](https://kb.controld.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Just as a bit of a footnote, if a site is having a problem with a particular user, they can potentially identify them again and again by looking at the browser info, which, while not as unique as a fingerprint, can certainly help them identify a particular problem person who keeps coming back on different IPs. See: https://www.whatsmybrowser.org/

That browser information can be hidden/spoofed too but it's not common knowledge and as far as I know, VPN type services do not automatically hide or scramble that kind of information. (If you use an unusual browser or unusual operating system, then this kind of "fingerprint" is all the easier to identify you with.)

Comment: There is an extension that has all the options to prevent browser fingerprinting
https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/trace-online-tracking-p/fhjjfbdhmjpcdckdoglijoahcdhndeco

Comment: @elias Browser fingerprinting cannot be completely blocked. It can be reduced, but it is always possible.

Comment: @forest "Blocking" browser fingerprinting is a bit of a misnomer.  There is only controlling what fingerprint data can be collected.  Multiple different machines in completely different locations can produce identical browser fingerprints.